# MicroDb not restarting. Stuck at 'Instance being restarted' for several hours

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

MySQL microDB instance of Cloud SQL is stuck in restarting for several hours. It is showing 'Instance is being restarted' for a long time. I am not able to connect, take backup, restore or clone it.

I tried to restart it using cloud shell. It is giving error HTTPError 409: Instance or operation is not in an appropriate state

I also tried to clone it using cloud shell. Same error as above.

All restore buttons are disabled.

I am using this instance for several weeks and it was fine. Suddenly this issue has popped up today. [operation status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJyek.png)

Comment: A workaround that I am not too happy with: Created a new instance, restored the backup of the currently problematic instance into the new instance and then linked the new instance with my app engine. 

Problematic instance is still in the hung state and I cannot even delete it.

Answer (score 0):

GCP Support here, your Cloud SQL instance is affected by an internal issue. We are working to solve this. I will provide you with an update about it when is solved.